# Matplotlib - plot wont show up

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, python-3.4, sympy

I want to plot a function graph (using matplotlib) when a button is pressed, to do so I wrote the following code:

```
##--IMPORT
#Tkinter
from tkinter import Tk, ttk
from tkinter import Frame, LabelFrame, Button
from tkinter import FALSE
#Numpy
from numpy import linspace
#Sympy
from sympy import symbols,sympify,diff,N,log
#MathPlotLib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

_x = symbols("x")
_sympyFunction = None
_SP_mainSubPlot = None

def pr_draw(plotToDrawTo):

    _sympyFunction = sympify("log(x) + x")
    valuesRange = linspace(0.01, 3, 100)

    x = []
    y = []

    #Calculate y and x values  
    for i in range(0, len(valuesRange)):
        tempValue = N(_sympyFunction.subs(_x,valuesRange[i]))

        x.append(float(valuesRange[i]))
        y.append(float(tempValue))

    #Draw function graph
    plotToDrawTo.plot(x,y)

##--MAIN
if __name__== "__main__":

    _root = Tk()
    _root.title("Grafico Approsimativo")
    _root.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)

    _mainFrame = Frame(_root, bg = "black")
    _mainFrame.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)


    #Frames
    #Main Left
    _F_LeftMainFrame = Frame(_mainFrame)
    _F_LeftMainFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nw")  

    _F_RightMainFrame = Frame(_mainFrame, bg = "violet")
    _F_RightMainFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = "ne")


    #Left Content--------------------------
    _B_calculate = Button(_F_LeftMainFrame, text = "Draw", command = lambda: pr_draw(_SP_mainSubPlot))
    _B_calculate.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = "w")

    #Right Content--------------------------
    _F_mainPlotWindow = Figure(figsize = None, dpi = 100)

    _SP_mainSubPlot = _F_mainPlotWindow.add_subplot(111)
    _SP_mainSubPlot.grid(True)

    #HERE



    #Set master frame for Figure Obj
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(_F_mainPlotWindow, master = _F_RightMainFrame)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

The problem here is that when the button is pressed, nothing shows up in the plot window, the only way I could get this to work is by calling pr_draw(_SP_mainSubPlot) where I inserted the #HERE line: If the function is called there it will work, but not from the button., why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to redraw the canvas after you have plotted to it.

Adding the line

```
plotToDrawTo.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
```

at the end of your `pr_draw` function should do that.

Note that I also had to add `_root.mainloop()` at the end of the script to actually show the window.

Comment: Awesome thanks! And for the _root.mainloop(), I just forgot to copy it in the question.